# What is the correct way to bind taskid property inside a replicator activity?

Tags: sharepoint, binding, workflow

I want to bind taskid to createTask and onTaskChanged activity that are inside my replicator activity configured to run in parallel mode.

I have bound it to a workflow field created by me but it seems to have some concurrency problem because I have bound a different parallel block of code to the same field.

What is the correct way to bind taskid property inside a replicator activity?

Answer (score 1):

In CreateTask go to Properties. 
Click TaskItemId and click bind. 
Bind it to a new property. 
In this property setter, value will give you task Id. 
This property setter is called every time a new task is created. 
Generate Edit Task Link here and send email if you want

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that all properties (taskProperties, taskBeforeProperties, taskAfterProperties, TaskId and TaskItemId) should be bound properly for parallel  replicator activity. I'm still looking solution for that problem. Workaround is to create customActivity with all these properties inside it and place it into replicator. If some other parameters needed inside customActitivty you may create your own dependencyProperty. 
If someone know another approaches to run replicator in parallel mode, say it to me.

Comment: My answer is exactly provide some workaround, but SPWFman sayd wrong info. So what is the problem above?